# Validate nested lists for unique values without looping same list multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

Say I have a collection of nested lists and in each of those lists I want to make sure all values are unique based on the `id` property.
I can easily loop through each list and sub lists to check this but I'm wondering how to do the equivalent with FluentValidation.

If I have a `CustomData` object that looks like

```
{
  "continents": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "countries": [
        {
          "id": "UK",
          "cities": [
            {
              "id": "London",
              "streets": [
                {
                  "id": "1"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can make a custom fluentvalidator for this object; `public class CustomDataValidator : AbstractValidator<CustomData>` and add a rule to check uniqueness in `Continents`:

```
RuleFor(customData => customData.Continents)
    .Must(continents) => HaveUniqueValues(continents))
    .WithMessage(x => "Continents contain duplicates")
    .When(x => !customData.Continents.IsNullOrEmpty());


...
bool HaveUniqueValues(IEnumerable<Continent> collection){
    return collection.Distinct(x => x.Id).Count() == collection.Count(); //simplified for this example
}
```

But how would I make sure the rules for all nested lists (countries, cities, streets) like countries wont loop through parent lists again?

Another rule for countries like below would iterate continents again:

```
RuleFor(customData => customData.Continents)
    .Must(continents => continents.All(c => !c.Countries.IsNullOrEmpty() && HaveUniqueValues(c.Countries)))
    .WithMessage(x => "Continents contain duplicates")
    .When(x => !customData.Continents.IsNullOrEmpty());
```

Comment: Are you trying to ensure no duplicate continents exist? No duplicate countries? Cities? The code you posted for checking unique values was "simplified for this example" yet it is crucial information. Your definition of "uniqueness" will drive the solution.

Comment: @GregBurghardt All of them. I didn't think the validation was important but I've added a more concrete example that checks uniqueness based on the ID property